# How to remove files containing string in specific place?

Tags: batch-file

How do I remove files, which have a specific string in a specific place in their filename, using a batch file?

I want to remove files containig specific strings, entered by the end user.

For example, I want to remove all files containing `2019` from several directories where the filename looks like this:

```
FILE 2019.03.09.FILE.2019.XXX
```

I have this code for this:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE REMOVE FILES
@ECHO:
SET /p _FileNumber= Enter file number You want to remove:

del /q /s "C:\Directory1\*%_FileNumber%.*"
del /q /s "C:\Directory2\*%_FileNumber%.*"

PAUSE
```

I enter specific number and it works, but also removes all files that have a Year in name.

Can I add something that will take variable from number before extension field?

Comment: The code you have provided is not representative of the task you have laid out in your question. On StackOverflow we help you to fix a specific issue in your provided code, but the code you currently have works as it is written. Your question is therefore off topic here. In order to bring your question on topic, you need to attempt to match the position in your code to identify filenames with that string in that position. In your example simply using e.g. `"C:\Directory2\*.%_FileNumber%.*"` may work though!

Comment: FYI, your files can be accessed with regex `FILE [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.FILE\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.XXX`. What should be done is: `for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /s /b /a-d * ^| findstr /rc:"FILE [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.FILE\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.XXX"') do del "%%~fA"`. Having in mind that `2019` should be added where it exists, use `for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /s /b /a-d * ^| findstr /rc:"FILE %_FileNumber%\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.FILE\.%_FileNumber%\.XXX"') do del "%%~fA"` and it should certainly work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for all Your answers and comments. I solved the issue in other way. I simply added a dot before percentage sign, and removed the one at the end. Since there isn't one before date it solves the problem. Works fine - tested with about 50 different file names combinations.

```
del /q /s "C:\Directory1\*.%_FileNumber%*"
del /q /s "C:\Directory2\*.%_FileNumber%*"
```

Comment: Do you mean like I provided in my comment seven hours ago?

Comment: @mgk if yes, then I think you should consider accepting (and optionally upvoting) my answer since it does with a better way what you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If **all** the files you provided are in the format `FILE yyyy.mm.dd.FILE.yyyy.ext`, then use `findstr` with regular expressions:

```bat
@echo off
title REMOVE FILES
echo:
set /p "_FileNumber=Enter file number You want to remove: "

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /S /B /A-D "*" ^| findstr /RC:"FILE %_FileNumber%\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.FILE\.%_FileNumber%\.ext"') do del /F /A "%%~fA"

pause
```

This, will delete for sure all files containing user input in the format you mentioned.

Regular expression explanation:

- `/R` enables it in `findstr`
- `\` is an escape character
- `.` is a wildcard; it means any character, so it is escaped with `\` as you want a real dot.
- `[0-9]` means to match only if one of the characters in `[]` exist so, if any of the characters `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9` exist.

For more information about the commands used, please type in `cmd.exe`:

- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `title /?`
- `echo /?`
- **`findstr /?`** explains regular expressions accepted
- `pause /?`
- `dir /?`
- `del /?`